# New page in print in XSL HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xslt-1.0

I need to put text in my XSL, but this text need to display after a page break in print. I know i can hide elements unless printing (media-print), but can I add some spacers until a page break? CSS property? Or is there a special XSL instruction? Can I do it with JavaScript?

I tried page-break-after CSS property, but It doesn't seem to work or I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got it working. `page-break-before` CSS property did the trick!

```
<div style="page-break-before: always">New page in print</div>
```

This will show after a page-break!